# PHP Laravel DocuSign Embedded Signing: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

Currently Using:
Laravel 5.5

"tucker-eric/docusign-rest-client": "^1.0",

"tucker-eric/laravel-docusign": "^0.1.1"

**Intention is to generate a URL so all customers / agents sign on the spot**

Here is what I have so far

**I  first create the client**

```
$client = new DocuSign\Rest\Client([
        'username'       => env('DOCUSIGN_USERNAME'),
        'password'       => env('DOCUSIGN_PASSWORD'),
        'integrator_key' => env('DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATOR_KEY'),
        'host'           => env('DOCUSIGN_HOST')
    ]);
```

**For each signer I assign their name and email**

```
    $templateRole1 = $client->templateRole([
        'email'     => 'abc@gmail.com',
        'name'      => 'abc',
        'role_name' => 'Agent'
    ]);

    $templateRole2 = $client->templateRole([
        'email'     => 'abc123@gmail.com',
        'name'      => 'abc',
        'role_name' => 'Purchaser 1'
    ]);

    $templateRole3 = $client->templateRole([
        'email'     => 'abc124@gmail.com',
        'name'      => 'abc124',
        'role_name' => 'Purchaser 2'
    ]);

    $templateRole4 = $client->templateRole([
        'email'     => 'abc125@gmail.com',
        'name'      => 'abc125',
        'role_name' => 'Seller'
    ]);
```

**I create the envelope (not sure why it sends it, I dont want it sent yet**

```
    $envelopeDefinition = $client->envelopeDefinition([
        'status'         => 'sent',
        'email_subject'  => '[DocuSign PHP SDK] - Signature Request Sample',
        'template_id'    => '***abc-123-',
        'template_roles' => [
            $templateRole1,
            $templateRole2,
            $templateRole3,
            $templateRole4,
        ],
    ]);
```

**Envelope options just because even tho I don't have any**

```
    $envelopeOptions = $client->envelopes->createEnvelopeOptions([]);
```

**Creates the final envelope**

```
    $envelopeSummary = $client->envelopes->createEnvelope($envelopeDefinition, $envelopeOptions);
```

**Prepare the embedding so I can extract the URL**

```
        $envelopeApi = $client->envelopes;
        $recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest();
        $recipient_view_request->setReturnUrl('https://www.example.net/callback/docusign');
        $recipient_view_request->setClientUserId((string) $client->getAccountId());
        $recipient_view_request->setAuthenticationMethod("None");

    try {
            $signingView = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView($client->getAccountId(), $envelopeSummary->getEnvelopeId(), $recipient_view_request);
        } catch (DocuSign\eSign\ApiException $e){        
            echo "Error connecting Docusign : " . $e->getResponseBody()->errorCode . " " . $e->getResponseBody()->message;
        }
```

Which returns:

```
object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\ErrorDetails)#419 (1) { ["container":protected]=> array(2) { ["error_code"]=> string(20) "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY" ["message"]=> string(94) "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Input string was not in a correct format." } } Error connecting Docusign : INVALID_REQUEST_BODY The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Input string was not in a correct format.done
```

My question is what I'm doing wrong to get this error returned, and why is it sending the email to the people signing as I didn't explicitly tell it

Thanks

Comment: hey the status parameter in $envelopeDefinition is 'sent' is this what could be causing the sending? What other options are available. As for your error the request you are sending is not in the format it expects review the API for this method createRecipientView and make sure you sending all the correct parameters.

Comment: yeah the I found this for you https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php look at line 95 also there is some code there that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the DocuSign Laravel facades by Eric Tucker. If you need to add attributes beyond what Eric's facades provide then you'll need to fork that project to add support for the additional attributes.

You have a server-resident template. You want to use it to provide an embedded signing ceremony in your Laravel app for the signers.

For a signer recipient to be marked as an embedded signer, set the `client_user_id` attribute to the signer object. For example:

```
$templateRole1 = $client->templateRole([
    'email'     => 'abc@gmail.com',
    'name'      => 'abc',
    'role_name' => 'Agent',
    'client_user_id' => '1000'
]);
```

Note that the client_user_id should uniquely identify this signer as a user within your application.

#### Re: Why are the signers receiving email invites to sign?

Setting the `client_user_id` will suppress the email notification to the signer.

#### Re: should the envelope be sent or be in draft status?

You want `sent` status, which enables recipients to sign via the embedded signing ceremony you'll be next creating.

#### Re: Envelope Options for creating the envelope.

Normally, you don't supply an EnvelopeOptions when creating an envelope with the PHP SDK. However, Eric Tucker could be combining calls or something. You'll need to check his code.

Here is a standard PHP call to send an envelope:

```
    $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($args['base_path']);
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
    $api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    $envelope_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($api_client);
    $results = $envelope_api->createEnvelope($args['account_id'], $envelope_definition);
    $envelope_id = $results->getEnvelopeId();
```

#### Obtaining the redirect URL for the embedded signing ceremony

Normal PHP way to do this is to call the `createRecipientView` method. You need to provide the signer's name, email, and client_user_id from the create envelope step, along with the authentication method your app is using to identify the signer. And, of course, the envelope id too.

Example:

```
    # Create the Recipient View request object
    $authentication_method = 'None'; # How is this application authenticating
    # the signer? See the `authenticationMethod' definition
    # https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient

    $recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
        'authentication_method' => $authentication_method,
        'client_user_id' => $envelope_args['signer_client_id'],
        'recipient_id' => '1',
        'return_url' => $envelope_args['ds_return_url'],
        'user_name' => $envelope_args['signer_name'], 
        'email' => $envelope_args['signer_email']
    ]);
    # 4. Obtain the recipient_view_url for the signing ceremony
    # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
    $results = $envelope_api->createRecipientView($args['account_id'], $envelope_id,
        $recipient_view_request);

    $redirect_url = $results['url'];
```